# How to properly mimic the encoding and decoding equivalents of Python 2.x into Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class listener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        data.replace("\\\"","").decode('unicode_escape')\
        .encode('ascii','ignore').replace("\n"," ").strip()
        twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
```

This works perfectly in Python 2.x, but not in 3.x. I went through a lot of content  about how to implement encoding & decoding in Python 3.x. But, even if I convert the data to bytes() instead of str and run it, it still gives an error. So, how to exactly convert it into Python 3.x code.

I tried this but did not work. Still throws an error saying encode and decode does not work with str, expects bytes object.

```
class listener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        data=bytes(data,'ascii')
        data=data.decode('unicode-escape')
        newtweet=data.replace("\\\"","").encode('ascii','ignore')\
        .replace("\n"," ").strip()
```

Comment: It would be nice to give the exact error message with its traceback...

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "streamer.py", line 35, in <module>
    twitterStream.filter(languages=["en"],track=["India","#India"])
    newtweet=data.replace("\\\"","").encode('ascii','ignore').replace("\n"," ").strip()
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'